# UILabel animated fade in out isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uilabel, fade

I am trying to build an introduction to my app with UILabels fading in and out. I have two labels. I want the first one to fade in, stay on the screen for 4 seconds. Then second label should fade in and stay on the screen for 4 seconds. Then it should fade out both the labels.

I have the following code but it does not do anything since it goes straight to the final state. I have the following method in viewDidAppear(). What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) animateLabels
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"First Label Display" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:4.0];
    firstLabel.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Second Label Display" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:6.0];
    secondLabel.alpha = 1;
    [UILabel commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Hide Labels" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:10.0];
    secondLabel.alpha = 0;
    firstLabel.alpha=0;
    [UILabel commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: You might want to see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684200/iphone-sequential-animation-with-setanimationdelay/1684273#1684273

Comment: You are mixing up setAnimationDelay and setAnimationDuration

Answer (score 3):

Use block based animation & chain your animations together. So there are 3 steps. label1 fadesIn, Label2 fadesIn, finally Label3 fadesIn. I have written the code below for fading in label1 & label2. Fading out is simple. I think you can fill in the rest. Its straight-forward from here...

Try this -

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                      delay:4 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^(void) 
 {
     [firstLabel setAlpha:1.0];
 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) 
 {
     if(finished)
     {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                               delay:4.0 
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                          animations:^(void) 
          {
              [secondLabel setAlpha:1.0];
          } 
                          completion:^(BOOL finished) 
          {
              if(finished)
              {
                  //put another block her to hide both the labels.
              }
          }];
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Not a slight against this answer in any way, but does anyone have a way to chain block-based animations together where the indentation _doesn't_ look awful? I really like using them but my god does it make for some ugly code.

Comment: I know the indentation hurts my eyes but have no clue how to represent this better...

Comment: Thank you. Does this work for iOS 3.x too? Or should I not bother supporting devices running iOS 3.x?

Comment: this is block based animation. I dont think it will work in iOS3.X Well its tricky. Easiest thing is to not support iOS3 & less. but if you are planning to then you need to code this animation using the more complicated 2block method you posted in the question. I suggest you stick with supporting > iOS4.X

Answer (score 1):

I suggest rewriting this using blocks. First `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` and then nested `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. It's far more flexible, and there's no need to run on pre-blocks systems these days.

Also, your first animation as written wouldn't trigger for 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in **swift 4+**

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 4, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
    firstLabel.alpha = 1.0
}) { finished in
    if finished {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 4.0, options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            secondLabel.alpha = 1.0
        }) { finished in
            if finished {
                //put another block her to hide both the labels.
            }
        }
    }
}
```